# Issue running first project Django

Tags: python, django

I am running a tutorial about Python & Django and this tutorial teaches how to make a simple application Agenda.

So, I installed Django version 1.5.4 and followed all the steps to make a simple hello.
But the problem is when I run the server and try to see the example, the terminal at first shows `ImportError: No module named agenda`.

My project folder is this structure (is in home/myusername/projects/).

This is the tree of my project:

```
gerenciador
├── gerenciador
│   ├── agenda
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'agenda',) #1
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^$', 'agenda.views.index'),)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Olá mundo!')
```

When I put in **#1** gerenciador.agenda, my terminal outputs no error so it seems the problem is solved at first but when I go to the loopback address it gives me an ImportError.
I am running python 2.7

So, can you guys can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you mean `gerenciador.agenda` ?

Comment: I already did this but when running my loopback addr it outputs me `ImportError`

Comment: Ok. As Daniel Recommends, move it one level up.

Answer (score 2):

The `agenda` directory should not be inside the inner `gerenciador`. It should be one level up, on the same level as that directory, both of them inside the outer `gerenciador`.

Django would have done that for you automatically if you had done `manage.py startapp agenda`.

Comment: But this is a fault of Django? I am sure i did it correctly as is showed in the book. I did nothing more than `manage.py startapp..`

Comment: Problem solved. I think it was my mistake running the manager inside the `gerenciador` application. Thanks.